# GWT-platform dispatch + phonegap

Tags: cordova, rpc, gwtp, mgwt

I am using GWT-platform + mgwt + phonegap. I am trying to make a call to my server using GWTP actions, but the call does not go through in the iOS simulater. The call works on the mobile browser.
I was able to get RPC working though using-
    PhonegapUtil.prepareService((ServiceDefTarget) chartService,"www.text.com/a/", "b/cname" );

I enabled some logging and the asynccallback handler returns to the onFailure(..) method.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you whitelist the url you are trying to call?

Comment: yes i have the url in whitelist. That fixed the rpc but not the gwtp action dispatch calls.

Comment: What do you mean by it fixed the RPC? You have to apply prepareService to every service (also to the gwt action dispatch calls)

Comment: I had a few RPC calls in addition to gwt action dispatch. So you mean I have to apply prepareService for actions as well? Something like- PhonegapUtil.prepareService((ServiceDefTarget) action, "...", "...");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make GWT RPC calls work you will need to call the PhonegapUtil.prepareService method from gwt-phonegap.

If you are using gwt-platform you will need to do the same on their instance of the async service interface.